# Mock Location permission issue on release app

Tags: android, permissions, mocking, location

I developed Fake `GPS application` and all my codes work nicely on debug mode.

When i try "mock location" on `**release version**`, i got this error;

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Requires `ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION` permission
```

I already had `ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION` in debug/AndroidManifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

And already "Allow Mock Location" checked in "Delevoper Options".

Finally; i cant add `"ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"` on `main/AndroidManifest.xml`. Android Studio dont approve this permission.

I tried on `Samsung Note 3, V: 4.4.2`

Whole of the expection;

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Requires ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
  at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.addTestProvider(ILocationManager.java:944)
  at android.location.LocationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.java:1205)
  at egebit.getlocation.MapsActivity.mockLocation(MapsActivity.java:201)
  at egebit.getlocation.MapsActivity$2.onClick(MapsActivity.java:118)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4652)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19311)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In that case you are just adding for debug, but it's needed on release too.

You could add to Manifest(not debug) file with ignore value

```
  <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"
    tools:ignore="MockLocation" />
```

Comment: Thats solved my problem, hank you so much @Blackkara.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you so much!